# Adding min max to custom contol range bar

Tags: c#

I've written a custom range slider in c#. So far I have 3 properties 'Min, Max, and Value'. As suggested I need to do the following:
1. Adjust the Value property to check it stays between Min and Max.
2.Change the name of the percent variable since it no longer stores the percentage.
3.Use either floats or ints everywhere for the value, don't mix them because you could lose precision.
4.Create a method to update the value by mouse and call that from the event handlers.

I am not sure the best way to implement these changes. I was hoping for some help.

```
namespace jmRangeSlider
{
    public partial class rangeSlider : UserControl
    {
        public rangeSlider()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            label1.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            this.ForeColor = SystemColors.Highlight; // set the default color the RangeSlider
        }

        protected float percent = 0.0f; // Protected because we don't want this to be accessed from the outside

        // Create a Value property for the RangeSlider
        public float Value
        {
            get
            {
                return percent;
            }
            set
            {
                // Maintain the value between 0 and 100
                if (value < 0) value = 0;
                else if (value > 100) value = 100;
                percent = value;
                label1.Text = value.ToString();
                //redraw the RangeSlider every time the value changes
                this.Invalidate();
            }
        }

        int minValue = 0;
        public int MinValue
        {
            get
            {
                return this.minValue;
            }

            set
            {
                this.minValue = value;
            }
        }

        int maxValue = 100;
        public int MaxValue
        {
            get
            {
                return this.maxValue;
            }

            set
            {
                this.maxValue = value;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);
            Brush b = new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor); //create brush that will draw the background of the range bar
            // create a linear gradient that will be drawn over the background. FromArgb means you can use the Alpha value which is the transparency
            LinearGradientBrush lb = new LinearGradientBrush(new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height), Color.FromArgb(50, Color.White), Color.FromArgb(0, Color.White), LinearGradientMode.Vertical);

            // calculate how much has the RangeSlider to be filled for 'x' %
            int width = (int)((percent / 100) * this.Width);
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(b, 0, 0, width, this.Height);
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(lb, 0, 0, width, this.Height);
            b.Dispose(); lb.Dispose();
        }

        private void rangeSlider_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // maintain the label in the center of the RangeSlider
            label1.Location = new Point(this.Width / 2 - 21 / 2 - 4, this.Height / 2 - 15 / 2);
        }

        protected override void OnMouseClick(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            int x = e.X;
            int y = e.Y;

            int val = (x * 100) / this.Width; //when click get value within progress bar
            int screenX = Cursor.Position.X;

            label1.Text = screenX.ToString();
            this.Value = val;
        }

        protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                //this.Value += 1;
                int x = e.X;
                int val = (x * 100) / this.Width; //when click get value within progress bar
                label1.Text = val.ToString();
                this.Value = val;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? Which parts of the code are producing them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add properties to hold & set Min and Max. You could add checking to make sure Min < Value < Max, but I have left that out for simplicity.

```
public float Min { get; set; }
public float Max { get; set; }
```

Then, adjust the Value property to check it stays between Min and Max. Then change the paint method like so:

```
int width = (int)((Value - Min) * this.Width / (Max - Min));
```

Change the setting code to:

```
Value = Min + (e.X / this.Width * (Max - Min));
```

Further suggestions:

1. Change the name of the `percent` variable since it no longer stores the percentage, for example call it `value`.
2. Use either floats or ints everywhere for the value, don't mix them because you could lose precision.
3. Create a method to update the value by mouse and call that from the event handlers, like shown below.

-

```
protected override void OnMouseClick(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    UpdateValue(e)
}

protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) UpdateValue(e);
}

private void UpdateValue(MouseEventArgs e) {
    Value = Min + (e.X / this.Width * (Max - Min));
}
```

Comment: How would you change the 'percent' variable to be correct? also how do you add in a Min and Max property?

Comment: I have updated my answer regarding the properties. The property Value is an absolute value in my answer. If you would like to know the percentage between Min and Max you can calculate it like this: `percent = (Value - Min) / (Max - Min)`.